# GeoServer Maven Build Plugin AuthKey Authentication

Tags: maven, plugins, geoserver, osgeo, ogc

[Key Authentication](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.15.2/extensions/geoserver-2.15.2-authkey-plugin.zip) plugin is not available for GeoServer 2.15.2. I need to use this plugin and I would like to get an insight on how to use Maven to do so.

I wonder if I should download the GeoServer@2.15.2 codebase from the GitHub repository and start from that point or if I should download the war file and deploy it and start from this point. I have never used Maven before, and I would like to know if I should run the command to build the plugin authkey from a specific directory in the project directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

I decided migrating geoserver to the stable version and it was the best solution.